# jquery properties.. while clicking a tab it should not do anything..hw do i add this feature?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

Im trying to create a ui tab using jquery and in this one I m planning to add 4 tabs and I want to add the option like if first tab is open, the other three should be disabled. the clikc option should not open a new div for the ones except the one ive kept open.. how do i do that??

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the jqueryui tabs plugin from here? (http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/) If you are, there are several events you could wire to disable the other tabs such as the load, select, enable, or disable event.

Answer (score -1):

add a class 'activeTab' to the active tab. and write something like this.

```
$('.alltabs').not('.activeTab').click(function(){

return false;

});
```

Comment: interesting, what is the reason that is quicker?

Comment: from the jquery docs: The .not() method will end up providing you with more readable selections than pushing complex selectors or variables into a :not() selector filter. In most cases, it is a better choice.

Comment: ok, thanks for the info. It does not say it's faster, but it's better and more readable. I agree with that.